# Is it haram to keep a picture of people wearing amulets?

Tags: halal-haram

I remembered that I kept a picture of someone wearing amulet in necklace. But the thing is I'm not sure if that thing is amulet or not I just keep the picture of person just to look at them. However, I do not believe that amulets can bring good luck or whatsoever. Have I made a sin?

Answer (score 0):

Taking pictures isn't good in Islam first of all and keeping that in amulets arent good for a muslim.

**Aala Hazrat Ash Shah Imam Ahmed Raza Khan Qaadiri**  mentions
in the Khutbah of Ataya al-Qadeer fi Hukmit Tasweer, the book
wherein he proves that to take and keep photographs of living objects
are Haraam. A few short narrations from the said book are presented
below:

In the Khutbah Aala Hazrat  says, **“All Praise is for Allah, Who is
the Creator and the Maker of features, who blessed us with good
features and alone, He created the minutest of minute things in the
universe and He destined severe chastisement and intense
punishment for those who replicate that which He has created.
They replicate Allah’s creation, then let them create one speck or
one grain of wheat. Durood and salaams upon him ﻿, who came
destroying idols and who commanded big and small photographs to
be Haraam, and said it to be a major sin; and peace and salutations
upon his family and companions and upon his respected (son)
descendant Ghaus-e-Azam and peace and blessings upon the entire
Ummah, according to their status and excellence. My Creator! I
seek your refuge from the whispering of shaitaan and I seek Your
protection, so that he does not come near me.”**

Aala Hazrat  further quotes the following Hadith Shareef; **Hazrat
Abu Hurairah  says that the Beloved Rasool ﻿ said,
“Jibra’eel (alaihis salaam) came to me and said, ‘Last night I came
to present myself in your Holy Court, but I did not enter as there
were pictures (of living things) on the doorway and there is a
curtain in the house which has pictures on it and there is a dog in
the house, thus please command that the pictures that are there
should have the heads removed, so that it takes the form of a tree
and cut the cloth of the curtain in two parts and use it to make
pillows so that the figures on it may be destroyed and let the dog be
removed’ The Prophet ﻿ did exactly that.”**